# How to edit a non shared file

Tags: c#, file, shared

I have a file opened by a third party program in non shared way. I know it won't cause any problem if I edit the file on the fly, and wondering if there is any way to do it without

- uninstall the program
- close the program
- restart the computer

Thanks a lot

If `C#` cannot do it, any other method is welcome.

Comment: in theory there are ways (with and without C#) - but basically all of them involve some sort of "hacking"... why exactly do you need to do this ?

Comment: Because the person who write the program doesn't consider all the senarios and now I need to do it. Thanks

Comment: That didn't answer my question... some other points: please show some source code... what have you tried ?